# Looking for an example of a non-random experiment...

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

In probability theory, the experiments are defined as random (e.g., tossing the coin). But someone give an example of a non-random example? I struggle because any experiment before it happens has some level of uncertainty...

Thanks

Comment: Take the coin and place it carefully heads up on the table.

Comment: But if earthquake happens at this moment, can you be in the output ?

Comment: Sure, this is known as a degenerate random variable $X$ for which there exists $c\in\mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb P(X=c)=1$. There is no randomness involved, although $X$ still meets the measurability requirements to be a random variable.

Comment: There is no randomness involved in a the process of tossing the coin. But there is randomness in the external environment.  With such definition, I think we can think of any future event as random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An early and historical example of the probability of a non-random event is **Laplace's Rule of succession** : what's the probability that the sun will rise tomorrow.